# How to use loops to merge PDF files using Python

Tags: python, pdf, merge

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter, PdfFileMerger

merger =PdfFileMerger()

merger.append(PdfFileReader(open("seperated1 PDF file556.pdf", 'rb')))
merger.append(PdfFileReader(open("seperated1 PDF file557.pdf", 'rb')))
merger.append(PdfFileReader(open("seperated1 PDF file558.pdf", 'rb')))
merger.append(PdfFileReader(open("seperated1 PDF file559.pdf", 'rb')))
merger.append(PdfFileReader(open("seperated1 PDF file560.pdf", 'rb')))


merger.write("output01.pdf")
```

I want to merge all Pdf files but I don't know how to use a loop in this case, so I input one by one like the code above.

How do I make use of a loop here to merge all pdf files?

*I have: "*seperated1 PDF file1~660.pdf*"

[Captured vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfNPX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter, PdfFileMerger

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for n in range(1,601):
    merger.append(PdfFileReader(open(f"seperated1 PDF file{n}.pdf", 'rb')))

merger.write("output01.pdf")
```

Comment: Thank you I copied your code and well worikng about our team office work Thank Sir!